# upload JSON from Google Drive to smartheet via api

Tags: java, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am trying to have JSON files that are created by form software (Prontoforms) adn saved in a google drive, automatically insert new rows on existing sheet into Smartsheet via API.
I am new to API so don't know where to start.
Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you've described is certainly achievable.  You'd need to write a script that would read the JSON files from Google Drive, and then use the Smartsheet API to [add new rows](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?java#add-row(s)) in Smartsheet.

Since you're new to the API, a good starting point would be to acquaint yourself with the Smartsheet API by reviewing the documentation, starting here:  http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#overview.

When you're ready to start coding, you might consider using the [Smartsheet Java SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk) to implement this integration with Smartsheet.  (The SDK provides built-in functions for interacting with the Smartsheet API, so you don't have to build everything from scratch yourself.)  The API Documentation contains [sample code](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?java#java-sample-code) that shows how to use the Java SDK to execute any operation, including [Add Row(s)](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?java#add-row(s)).

From the API Documentation:

```
// Set the Access Token
Token token = new Token();
token.setAccessToken("INSERT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE");

// Use the Smartsheet Builder to create a Smartsheet
Smartsheet smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().setAccessToken(token.getAccessToken()).build();

// Specify cell values for first row.
List<Cell> cellsA = new Cell.AddRowCellsBuilder().addCell(7960873114331012, true).addCell(642523719853956, "New status").build();

// Specify contents of first row.
Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder().setCells(cellsA).setToBottom(true).build();

// Specify cell values for second row.
List<Cell> cellsB = new Cell.AddRowCellsBuilder().addCell(7960873114331012, true).addCell(642523719853956, "New status").build();

// Specify contents of second row.
Row rowB = new Row.AddRowBuilder().setCells(cellsB).setToBottom(true).build();

// Add rows to sheet.
smartsheet.sheetResources().rowResources().addRows(sheetId, Arrays.asList(rowA, rowB));
```